# Public available binary dataset

Tags: dataset

does anyone know if there exists some binary dataset that i can freely download?

If possible, i prefer dataset in textual format and inspired by some real phenomenon.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of possibilities for this,  please take a look at the literature.  I will give you some options below:

The popular Bliss insect data [here](http://www.stat.nthu.edu.tw/~swcheng/Teaching/stat5230/lab/02.05_BinomialData_prediction.html).

"Modelling binary data" by Collet [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584883243).

"Analysis of binary data" by Cox and Snell [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412306204)

"An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models" by Dobson and Barnett [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Generalized-Edition-Chapman-Statistical/dp/1584889500)

Free data sets from JSE [here](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/jse_data_archive.htm).

In this [paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2529311?uid=3738032&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=47698889017597), you can find references to 22 data sets.

In this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0015626481903643), you can find 31 data sets.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Also see http://hbiostat.org/data, especially data from the Titanic.