# Free data set for comparing kernel logistic regression and regular logistic regression

Tags: dataset, kernel-trick

I'm looking for a data set that is easily accessible for comparing Kernel Logistic Regression (KLR) and regular logistic regression.  All the paper that I find using KLR use synthetic data sets.  I'm most interested in data sets with continuous variables, so I can apply the squared exponential kernel.

Data sets with a binary target and spatial predictor variables would also be interesting.

Comment: [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26591/public-available-binary-dataset/26592#26592) is a compilation of binary data sets.

Comment: Comparison of algorithms is not something you can do on a single set, especially cherry-picked for a particular outcome.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of suitable datasets at the [UCI repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/).